# Add service reference fail

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, callback, net.tcp

I have WCF Service, that has callback.
When I have 25 methods in callback all fine, but if I add 26-th method, Visual Studio(2013) can't update or add service reference. WTF?

Error message:
The URI prefix is not recognized.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://127.0.0.1:9001/XXX.WCF/WCFService/mex'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://127.0.0.1:9001/XXX.WCF/WCFService/mex'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: What is the errormessage? Can you try with the svcutil to generate your client?

Comment: Error message: The URI prefix is not recognized. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://127.0.0.1:9001/XXX.WCF/WCFService/mex'. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://127.0.0.1:9001/XXX.WCF/WCFService/mex'. If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again

Comment: What is the 26th callback you add?